# How to expose dynamically amount of data to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have an app were I need to fetch random questions from a database and expose them to qml dynamically.

So I created a class to store each dataset:

```
class Question : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int id READ id)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString askedQuestion READ askedQuestion)
public:
    Question(int id,
             QString askedQuestion);

    int getId() const;
    QString getAskedQuestion() const;

private:
    int mId;
    QString mAskedQuestion;
};
```

And fill them in annother class. In reality it is derrived from an SQLDatabaseModel:

```
class QuestionGenerator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QuestionGenerator(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE QVector<Question> getRandomQuestions(int count) const
    {
        // simplified in reality we fetch random questions from a database. 
        // the point is we need to add Questions to the vector
        // but this does not work since QObject based items cannot get copied
        QVector<Question> questions;
        questions.reserve(count);
        
        // add questions to vector
        
        return questions;
    }
};
```

I want to expose `Question` to QML to use the data from `Question` there so I need to derive it from `QObject`.

When I fetch the Questions randomly in `QuestionGenerator` it does not work because `QVector` does net the not supported copy constructor of `QObject`.

So how can I fix this?

Again what I want:

Fetch n Questions in C++ and expose them to QML so I can use the data to display.

Comment: You have to create Question as a pointer: Question *q = new Question(this); questions.reserve(q); Qt keeps care about deleting the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `QVector<Question>` because QObjects are not copyable. But you can use a `QVector<Question*>` (note the pointer). You can make as many copies as you want of a pointer.

There's other ways to solve your problem too. Like a QAbstractListModel. But the easy solution is just a pointer.

Comment: I tried the pointer approach but then I get this error: error: use of deleted function ‘QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<Question>::QQmlElement()’

Comment: The error seems to indicate you're still not using a pointer. `"QQmlElement<Question>"` Edit your question with your new code.